# Format Tokens Using HTML?

Tags: tokens

Is it possible to format the display results of a token? For instance, if the token is (contact.phone), is it possible to make the resulting phone number bold or a specific color?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be in your document. For example just make the token bold/colored in your wysiwyg editor, or if you are editing html you can do like `<strong style="color:hotpink">{contact.phone}</strong>`

Comment: Thank you so much. The only issue is that I have an email token and I want the resulting email link to be a certain color. But, I can't get the resulting email address link to change. I can only change the color of the token text.

Comment: Nevermind! I just figured it out. Thank you again for your help.